# adding external texture to three.js scene object

Tags: javascript, three.js, texture-mapping

just getting my hands dirty with three.js and im curious on something that may be relatively simple…

I built a scene in the three.js editor and have figured out how to load the scene. In the editor, I added an image as a map texture but I realize it wont know where it is loaded externally on my server. So I've loaded the scene and objects and lights, but how can I map my textures to the objects?

```
// MATERIALS
    var wireframe = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textures/wireframe.jpg' );
    wireframe.wrapS = wireframe.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    wireframe.repeat.set( 4, 4 );
    var wireframeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ 
            map : wireframe, 
            side : THREE.DoubleSide 
        });


// LOAD SCENE
    var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
    loader.load( 'js/scene.js', function ( obj ) {
        obj.traverse( function( node ) { 
            if ( node instanceof THREE.Mesh ) { 
                node.castShadow = true; 
                node.receiveShadow = true;
                var plane = scene.getObjectByName( "plane", true );
                plane.material = wireframeMaterial;
            } 
        });

        scene.add( obj );
        render();
    });
```

When adding `plane.material = wireframeMaterial;` into the loader, all my objects just disappear… How can I properly map the wireframeMaterial the plane object?

working example with `var plane` and `plane.material` commented out:
http://goo.gl/czSg7P

Scene:
http://goo.gl/BAVgVS

Comment: I updated my answer once more and added a fiddle that seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

To map the texture you have to create a material using your texture and apply it to your plane.

If necessary you can set repetition of your texture with:

```
wireframe.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
wireframe.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
wireframe.repeat.set( 4, 4 );
```

And then you need to do something like this:

```
material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ map : wireframe, side : THREE.DoubleSide });
plane.material = material;
```

### EDIT

You create a scene inside a scene. Since the loader returns a scene and then you add it again to a scene. This will give issues for sure.

Try to replace `scene.add( obj );` with this in your loader:

```
for( var i = 0; i < obj.children.length; i++ ){
    scene.add( obj.children[i] );
}
```

Not sure if that causes the problem, but I made **[a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wilt/6yh1m1dz/)** and it all seems to work fine for me. The problem is that I can't load external sources in my fiddle so instead I had to use your image as `base64` string and the code becomes a bit different.

This means you have to change it a bit to make it work again with an image from your local folder.
If you exchange the Whole `//TEXTURE` part of the code with the following it should work:

```
var texture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'img/wireframe.jpg' );
texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.repeat.set( 1, 1 );

var textureMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ map: texture, side : THREE.DoubleSide });
```

Comment: thanks for the response and fiddle! my issue is, in the scene i have built… i have two objects... a cube and a plane. I only want the texture applied to the plane.

if I remove `scene.add( obj );` then none of my objects are loaded from my scene. when I implement `for( var i = 0; i < obj.children.length; i++ ){
    scene.add( obj.children[i] );
}` then only the first object in my scene gets added, in this case the plane…